# Retrieve blob image into html php

Tags: php, mysql

Display image from mysql.

```
<?php
        if(isset($id1)){
        $query="SELECT * FROM `newss` WHERE `id`=".$id1;
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        if(!$result){
            echo "<h3>News Not Availabel</h3>";
        }else{
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "
                        <img src=data:image/png;<?php echo ".$row['imges']."; ?> />

                         <figure class=date>

                            <h2>".$row['description']."</h2>
                            <div class=blog-detail-meta>
                                <span class=date><span class=fa fa-file-o></span>".$row['dates']."</span>

                            </div>
                        </header>
                        <hr>

                        <p>".$row['para1']." </p>
                        <p>
                            ".$row['para2']."
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            ".$row['para3']."
                        </p>




            ";
            }
        }
        }else{
            header("location:index.php");
        }
        ?>
```

Image not properly displayed.

I stored raw data blob (png format).  I want to display image, but only symbols are displayed.

Comment: <img src=data:image/png;base64,<?php echo ".$row['imges']."; ?> /> not work .where to correct can u help me

Comment: is this correct spelling `imges` or `images`

Comment: @ banditpanda  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'data' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,".$row['imges']."\" />" ;
```

Instead of

```
echo "<img src=data:image/png;<?php echo ".$row['imges']."; ?> />" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the table name really "newss"?
2. Don't do things like:

   ```
   echo "  
       HTML CODE  
   ";
   ```

Do this:

```
?>
   HTML CODE <?php echo $php_code;?>
<?php
```

You currently trying to use PHP opening Tag `<?php` within PHP self.

```
<?php
echo "<?php echo 'test';?>";
?>
```

PHP won't parse this, but will just echo it as pure text.

Change following line:

```
<img src=data:image/png;<?php echo ".$row['imges']."; ?> />
```

to:

```
<img src="data:image/png;".$row['imges'].";"/>
```

Also use double quotes for HTML-Parameters like `src="path/to/file.format"`.

Not being lazyis very important in coding!

If everything does not work, what is the output of `$row['imges']` ?